# iterate based on the number of records of a certain attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here is my json

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "id_cartao": 100000,
    "nome": "ewgkjgewkgw",
    "email": "qgijqgqg@ewqgijkgh.pt",
    "trienio": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "data_trienio": "2013-2016",
            "curso_id": 5,
            "oe_id": 1,
            "curso": {
                "id": 5,
                "curso": "TGEI"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "data_trienio": "2014-2017",
            "curso_id": 5,
            "oe_id": 1,
            "curso": {
                "id": 5,
                "curso": "TGEI"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

for example: there are two data_trienio records (2013-2016 and 2014-2017) and i'm managing to get them, however the each code will loop 5 times because there are 5 attributes in the trienio array, so it's printing 2013-2016 and 2014-2017 separately, 5 times.

how can i loop based on the actual number of data_trienio records? also i want to print the respective curso.curso (tgei) for each data_trienio record

thanks in advance and heres my actual code

```
            $.get('/admin/gerir/oe/getTrienio/' + id_cartao, function(data) {
                $.each(data.trienio, function(i, e) {
                    $.each(e, function(ind, elem) {
                        console.log(e['curso']['curso']);
                        console.log(e['data_trienio']);
                    });
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can loop it once only using loop like this

```
 $.get('js/test.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data.trienio,function(i,e){
            console.log(data.trienio[i]['curso']['curso']);
            console.log(data.trienio[i]['data_trienio']);
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop for the second time, one loop is enough :

```js
var data = {
    "id": 1,
    "id_cartao": 100000,
    "nome": "ewgkjgewkgw",
    "email": "qgijqgqg@ewqgijkgh.pt",
    "trienio": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "data_trienio": "2013-2016",
            "curso_id": 5,
            "oe_id": 1,
            "curso": {
                "id": 5,
                "curso": "TGEI"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "data_trienio": "2014-2017",
            "curso_id": 5,
            "oe_id": 1,
            "curso": {
                "id": 5,
                "curso": "TGEI"
            }
        }
    ]
};

$.each(data.trienio, function(i, e) {
    console.log("data_trienio : "+e['data_trienio']);
    console.log("curso : "+e['curso']['curso']);    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner loop, I would use something like:

```
$.get('/admin/gerir/oe/getTrienio/' + id_cartao, function ( data ) {
   for ( var i in data.trienio ) {
       // Just access your properties in here e.g: 
       console.log( data.trienio[i].id );
   }
});
```